# Implementing New UIPropertyMetadata for DependencyProperty in VS 2008 with VB.net 3.5

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Using Visual Studio 2008 with VB.net 3.5. Trying to implement a sorting solution from [[WPF] AUTOMATICALLY SORT A GRIDVIEW WHEN A COLUMN HEADER IS CLICKED by Thomas Levesque](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/03/27/wpf-automatically-sort-a-gridview-when-a-column-header-is-clicked/)

his code converted to VB.net by [converter.telerik.com](http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
Public Shared ReadOnly CommandProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", GetType(ICommand), GetType(GridViewSort), New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing, Function(o, e) 
    Dim listView As ItemsControl = TryCast(o, ItemsControl)
    If listView IsNot Nothing Then
        If Not GetAutoSort(listView) Then
            ' Don't change click handler if AutoSort enabled
            If e.OldValue IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.NewValue Is Nothing Then
                listView.[RemoveHandler](GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf ColumnHeader_Click))
            End If
            If e.OldValue Is Nothing AndAlso e.NewValue IsNot Nothing Then
                listView.[AddHandler](GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf ColumnHeader_Click))
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function))
```

Using old IDE I can't use it as given. I tried to convert the function to a regular function but I'm not sure where the `o` and `e` come from.

```
Public Shared ReadOnly CommandProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", GetType(ICommand), GetType(GridViewSort), New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing, getFuncA))

Public Shared Function getFuncA(ByVal o As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) 
    Dim listView As ItemsControl = TryCast(o, ItemsControl)
    If listView IsNot Nothing Then
        If Not GetAutoSort(listView) Then
            ' Don't change click handler if AutoSort enabled
            If e.OldValue IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.NewValue Is Nothing Then
                listView.[RemoveHandler](GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf ColumnHeader_Click))
            End If
            If e.OldValue Is Nothing AndAlso e.NewValue IsNot Nothing Then
                listView.[AddHandler](GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf ColumnHeader_Click))
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Compiler error `o is not declared` and `e is not declared`. How do I convert this to VB.net 3.5 using VS 2008. Thanks.

Comment: `o` and `e` should be `DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e` - `o` is an object where dependency property changed, `e` contains old and new values. event on DP change is generated by framework. getFuncA declaration should look ike event handler

Comment: @ASh Thanks a bunch. That's exactly what I was missing. I also changed `getFuncA` to `AddressOf getFuncA`. Wasn't understanding what the `UIPropertyMetadata` needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ASh comment. I just had to properly declare the getFuncA and use `AddressOf getFuncA`

```
Public Shared ReadOnly CommandProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command", _
                                      GetType(ICommand), _
                                      GetType(GridViewSort), _
                                      New UIPropertyMetadata(Nothing, AddressOf getFuncA))

Public Shared Function getFuncA(ByVal o As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim listView As ItemsControl = TryCast(o, ItemsControl)
    If listView IsNot Nothing Then
        If Not GetAutoSort(listView) Then
            ' Don't change click handler if AutoSort enabled
            If e.OldValue IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.NewValue Is Nothing Then
                listView.[RemoveHandler](GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, _
                        New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf ColumnHeader_Click))
            End If
            If e.OldValue Is Nothing AndAlso e.NewValue IsNot Nothing Then
                listView.[AddHandler](GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, _
                        New RoutedEventHandler(AddressOf ColumnHeader_Click))
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```